# New to Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I just started working with android studio, and because I only had experience with HTML/CSS/JavaScript and a little Java, I was hoping for some basic help.

1. I tried getting a button in my app that has a map. I wanted the button just a bove the map. Just doing:

   ```
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       Button but=new Button(this);
       but.setWidth(100);
       but.setHeight(100);
       mMap = googleMap;
   ```

didn't work. So how do i get a button in there, does it have to go through the code? I think I saw like a design tab where you can insert buttons, but I couldn't quite work it out.

2. Those xml files. My app (which is a basic app with map activity), has a activity_maps.xml where like that stats of elements of the project are defined (e.g i have a fragment object in my app, and in the xml file are the width and height of the fragment). But basically my questions is what are those xml files, ive never worked with things like that in my time with Java. Does every activity get a xml file? If i make a button, should i define its stats in the activity_maps.xml or should I make a separate one? Ext ext. If the questions are too basic or too broad, a link to a place with good documentation or tutorials would be good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a button in Android you need to create a button in an xml file. Also each activity will need an xml file. The xml is the UI for the user. You can add images, buttons, spinners, text etc. in them. So inside you're activity_maps.xml add 
`<button android:id="@+id/buttonid"> </button>`. Something similar to this. In your activity you'll want to create an instance of the button.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewByID(R.id.buttonid) //reference the ID of the button here
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/ I'd recommend following some of the documentation to get a better feel for how Android works and what everything is and how it works.

Comment: "In order to use a button in Android you need to create a button in an xml file" You can also do so in code.